# "Clear all messages" function in Chat

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

Currently it is possible to clear all messages with the scriptlet

```
javascript:void($('#chat').empty())
```

but I prefer having a specific in-page *button* or command (e.g. `/clear`).

---

(Added): It could look like this:

[image: screenshot]

and would allow users to get rid of things they don't care for (e.g., funny gifs they don't find funny) without resorting to flags or arguments.

Comment: Why would you want to remove all of the previous context of the current conversations?

Answer (score 2):

We're never to old for userscripts right?

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Clear Chat Button
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      1.0
// @description  Nukes everything in chat
// @author       UniKitty
// @match        http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @match        http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @match        http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function go() {
    var clearButton = document.createElement('button');
    clearButton.setAttribute("class", "button");
    clearButton.setAttribute("id", "clear-chat");
    clearButton.innerHTML = "Clear Chat";
    clearButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to clear the messages?')) {
        document.getElementById('chat').style.display = "none";
      }
    });


    var showButton = document.createElement('button');
    showButton.setAttribute("class", "button");
    showButton.setAttribute("id", "show-chat");
    showButton.innerHTML = "Refresh Chat";
    showButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.getElementById('chat').style.display = "";
    });

    var chatButtonContainer = document.getElementById('chat-buttons');
    chatButtonContainer.appendChild(clearButton);
    chatButtonContainer.appendChild(showButton);
}

go();
```

This adds in a button to chat:
 [image]
When you click it, there's a poopup asking for confirmation.[image]

And boom! Everything is gone![image]

To install it, just copy the text into a file and save it as `something.user.js`. Then install something like greasemonkey and drag the file into firefox (or chrome). Then install the userscript!
<sub>Sound effects not included</sub>

Comment: To get it back, reload the page

Comment: Actually now just press "Refresh Chat"

Answer (score -2):

The whole point of the chat is to show "saved state" of the room every time you enter.

If we wanted busted old statelessness, we'd use IRC, no?

Comment: I don't mean statelessness on the server side, but that after user has read every old messages, can clear the chat area on the client side so that it's easier to spot what's new. Think the IRC `/clear` command.

Comment: @kennytm the dotted line tells you this per the /faq

Comment: Except the user can't decide where the line is put. At least for me, the system often put the line too old than where I finished.

Comment: how is the line location chosen?

Comment: If you are used to IRC though it would be nice to have a similar feature to clear the previous posts from the browser, it doesn't need to affect other users, just clear your view.

Comment: There is a damn good reason for a `/clear`: People posting pictures of Justin Bieber in the chat.