# Chatroom clear screen?

Tags: feature-request, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Please support 'clear all messages' function in Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59967/please-support-clear-all-messages-function-in-chat)

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1945880#1945880

I think this is an awesome idea, often a lot of garbage loads up ontop of the chat, maybe someone posts a picture of something I don't want to see but it isn't really flag-worthy (in which case I open webkit inspector and delete the element from the DOM, which is annoying but works for me).

Can we get a "clear view" option in the chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like this idea, it also would not be difficult to implement. I use a javascript bookmark to clear the current screen but an official feature to do this would save others the effort of doing this themselves.

```
  document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = '';
```